# about the only thing you can do is -- meaning of "about"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> Most of the formatting options apply to the controls, as you’ll see in Chapter 2. For the
>   form itself, **about** the only thing you can do is change the look of the background for each
>   section: You can change the background color, or you can display an image as the background,
>   as described in the next two sections.

How is **about** used in that sentence?

Comment: From Macmillan Dictionary, [about](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/about) (sense 3): "used when you are making an extreme statement that you think is almost completely true or is probably true".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning is roughly the same as "almost".

> For the form itself, **almost** the only thing you can do...

Check this definition of [about](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/about), sense 8:

> 8) (informal) all but; almost  ⇒ "about ready"